# How can I find the area of sector that doesn't belong to a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

[image]

I've been trying to solve this question, but I don't know what I can assume.

At first I assumed that the area of the rhombus is the same as the area of the equivalent square, but realised quickly that that was wrong, and got the area of the rhombus to be:

$4\sqrt{12}$

But when it comes to finding the area of the sectors, I have no idea what I can assume. Would they be the same as a circle? One answer I found on the internet seemed to suggest so, but that feels wrong.

Comment: Do the arcs $BAD$ and $BCD$ mean *circular* arcs here? Confused as you emphasised that the sector "doesn't belong to a circle".

Comment: **Hint**: if $\theta$ is measured in radians, then for the area of a sector of a circle use this formula: $A=\frac{\theta}{2}r^2$ ($\theta$ is central angle, and $r$ is radius). You can easily find the value for $\theta$ in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the arcs $BAD$ and $BCD$ are arcs of 2 circles, with centres as given in the question. The word "arc" without qualification usually means part of a circle.

Comment: I see it now - the diagram just really doesn't look like it could be sectors of a circle, but obviously I see now the sector they are referring to. I sort of glimpsed over the letters, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

(Short Answer: The sector does belong to a circle).

The radius of the top arc is equal to CD,CB and AC (so it is reasonable to assume it is a circular arc) so the length of AC is 4cm and the two triangles are equilateral triangles. That means the vertices of the triangles are 60 degrees and there are two triangles so the arc subtends 120 degrees or 1/3 of a full circle. The top sector has area $\frac 1 3 (\pi r^2) = \frac {16} 3 \pi$ (Area 1).

The well known formula for the area of an equilateral triangle is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} x^2$ where x is a side length of the equilateral triangle. Since there are two of these triangles their total area is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x^2 = 8\sqrt{3}$ (Area 2).

The shaded area of the top half is Area 1 - Area 2 = $\frac {16} 3 \pi - 8\sqrt{3} \rightarrow \frac 1 3 \left( 16 \pi - 24 \sqrt{3} \right)$

The logo is symmetrical so the area of the shaded arc at the bottom is the same as the top so the total shaded area is  $$\frac 2 3 \left( 16 \pi - 24 \sqrt{3} \right)$$